# how to make user able to connect custom domain to our service? (eg shopify, medium, wordpress)

Tags: dns, subdomain, custom-domain

## Question

Using React for our Shopify-like service. basically the same functionality.
Where i am stuck is how do i Make user able to connect their domain to our websites specific domain or subdomain.

## eg.

#### User owned domain

> uniquedomain.com

#### Service domain

> user.myservice.com

#### from shopify

shopify allows user to add their domain to their shop. how does this work?

## conclusion

If user wants to add their domain to our specific url,
what tech should i be adopting for this feature?

currently using React, react-subdomain

*react subdomain*
https://github.com/bmullan91/express-subdomain

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using CNAME records or giving your users the IP address of your server to add in there DNS records.

How shopify does this -

Shopify gives the IP addresses of there load balancer to the users who wants to connect to their domain to the shopify shop.

The end user (domain owner) need to point there domain to the given Ip address, and you will have to have the virtual host setup at your end to recognise each domain.